# AngularJS: $watch function invoked. Which DOM element invoked it?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a $watch function:

```
$scope.$watch('something', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    ...
}, true);
```

I have three DOM form elements, each of which is a `something`.  When you make a change to any of them, the $watch function above is invoked.

Is it possible to determine, from within the $watch function, which of the three form fields invoked it AND get a reference to the corresponding DOM element?

Comment: Why all the three form fields have same ng-model="something"? Give out your html also

Comment: No, because DOM elements have nothing to do with watchers.

Comment: You should not care, if you give us some code we can probably recommend a better way.

Answer (score 0):

you need to watch on whole array and check manually all elements of array. Check its previous value and latest new value. If both are same then no change in then DOM elements otherwise there are some changes in the elements.

See JSFiddle example hope this will help you.
http://jsfiddle.net/imhassan66/Th6QM/

```
 $scope.$watch("aArr", function (newValue,oldValue) {
    console.log("array[0] old value: "+ oldValue[0].val);
    console.log("array[0] new value: "+ newValue[0].val);

}, true);
```